# Transmux two videos to side by side without reencoding

Tags: h.264, transcode, nalu

I am wondering if it would be possible to merge two videos (side by side) without transcoding. The streams are identical except the pictures are different. Think IP cameras on a LAN.

I am on a platform where I dont have compute power for real transcoding.

The codecs I am interested in is h264 and h265.

I am thinking something a long the lines of:

1. modify size of video plane of video A.
2. add data from video B to video A while adding offsets.

If you know of projects that has done this I would appreciate a pointer.

kind regards

jesper

Comment: Where are you playing these videos (output destination)? Can they not just be shown side-by-side by the playback system? PS: In H264 you cannot just expand the video plane. There is too much going on within the H264 bytes so it's not easy to edit like that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. :)

I am aware that I can achieve the end result with multiple players. I have done so in multiple projects. 

The reason this is interresting to me is that the possibility would open some interresting possibilities. 

*Some systems I work with can only accept a single video.

*Syncing between videos would be "taken care of".

*It could potentially be fast and lossless. 

*It could potentially be done on a small device where transcoding would not be possible.